# Vertically and horizontally center a heading underneath an image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have created the following **[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/93u7npfg/3/)** on a website that I'm building.

The first heading has 3 lines, whilst the other 2 just have one line. I have added a `min-height` to my boxes so they are all equal.

I would now like to center the heading on the vertical and horizontal axis.

I have tried to achieve this with flexbox, but it's only aligning horizontally. What am I doing wrong here?

```css
.container {
  width: 600px;
  max-width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.third {
  float: left;
  width: 32%;
  min-height: 227px;
  margin: 0 2% 2% 0;
  background: #fff;
}
.last {
  margin: 0 0 2% 0;
}
header {
  padding: 12px;
}
h2 {
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
img {
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <section class="third">
    <img src="http://bit.ly/1OTNPkt" alt="Kitten">
    <header>
      <h2>Title one which is slightly longer goes here</h2>
    </header>
  </section>
  <section class="third">
    <img src="http://bit.ly/1OTNPkt" alt="Kitten">
    <header>
      <h2>Title two</h2>
    </header>
  </section>
  <section class="third last">
    <img src="http://bit.ly/1OTNPkt" alt="Kitten">
    <header>
      <h2>Title three</h2>
    </header>
  </section>
</div>
```

**Update:**

I'm looking for a solution that supports IE including 9.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest to use nested flexbox, drop the `float` and `min-height` on the `section`. The flex layout is smart enough to get equal height automatically. For IE9 support, see the bottom part.

```css
.container {
  width: 600px;
  max-width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
}
.third {
  /* float: left; */
  width: 32%;
  /* min-height: 227px; */
  margin: 0 2% 2% 0;
  background: gold;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.last {
  margin: 0 0 2% 0;
}
header {
  padding: 12px;
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
h2 {
  margin: 0;
}
img {
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <section class="third">
    <img src="http://bit.ly/1OTNPkt" alt="Kitten">
    <header>
      <h2>Title one which is slightly longer goes here</h2>
    </header>
  </section>
  <section class="third">
    <img src="http://bit.ly/1OTNPkt" alt="Kitten">
    <header>
      <h2>Title two</h2>
    </header>
  </section>
  <section class="third last">
    <img src="http://bit.ly/1OTNPkt" alt="Kitten">
    <header>
      <h2>Title three</h2>
    </header>
  </section>
</div>
```

**Edit: IE9 support.** I would use some Javascript to do the equal height stuff, the following example using jQuery + CSS table cell to do the vertical center.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var maxHeight = 0;
  $("h2").each(function() {
    if ($(this).height() > maxHeight) {
      maxHeight = $(this).height();
    }
  });
  $("h2").height(maxHeight);
});
```

```css
.container {
  width: 600px;
  max-width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.third {
  float: left;
  width: 32%;
  /* min-height: 227px; */
  margin: 0 2% 2% 0;
  background: gold;
}
.last {
  margin: 0 0 2% 0;
}
header {
  padding: 12px;
}
h2 {
  margin: 0;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
img {
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <section class="third">
    <img src="http://bit.ly/1OTNPkt" alt="Kitten">
    <header>
      <h2>Title one which is slightly longer goes here</h2>
    </header>
  </section>
  <section class="third">
    <img src="http://bit.ly/1OTNPkt" alt="Kitten">
    <header>
      <h2>Title two</h2>
    </header>
  </section>
  <section class="third last">
    <img src="http://bit.ly/1OTNPkt" alt="Kitten">
    <header>
      <h2>Title three</h2>
    </header>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: Excellent solution, but I need to support IE including 9. Is there another solution?

Comment: Are you open to jQuery solution?

Comment: I'd prefer to do it purely with HTML and CSS if possible. I would be open to JQuery though if it's messy in HTML.

Answer (score 2):

Tried using `display: table` and it sort of works but it turns out that you can't use percentages for `border-spacing`

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/2dkycc1L/

Answer (score 1):

I made the whole grid using flexbox to make them all equal height and removed the min-height. The `header` element is also flexing to make the title vertically align in the middle: https://jsfiddle.net/5yq37fha/.